# MVC: Is it possible to have one custom ModelBinder AND the default binder on one model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, modelbinder

I would like to use my custom binder to deal with the constructor (necessary) and then have the default modelbinder fill in the rest of the properties as normal.

Edit: The custom one would run first of course.

Answer (score 1):

Mo.'s answer is correct. Inherit from the DefaultModelBinder then override CreateModel.
I'm just posting to provide sample codes.

The binder:

```
public class RegistrationViewModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder 
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        return new RegistrationViewModel(Guid.NewGuid());
    }
}
```

The model:

```
public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }    
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }

    public RegistrationViewModel(Guid id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

If your property will be settable (In this case its the Id), you need to exclude it from the bind:

```
[Bind(Exclude = "Id")]
public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, I think I have found a solution, and that is to override the createmodel method of defaultmodelbinder. I had additional help from here:
http://noahblu.wordpress.com/2009/06/15/modelbinder-for-objects-without-default-constructors/

It needed updating to use modelmetadata instead of setting the modeltype as shown in that link, due to a change they made in mvc. 
This is what I have ended up with as a first try that seems to work:

```
namespace NorthwindMVCApp.CustomBinders{

   public class NewShipperBinder<T> : DefaultModelBinder
{

    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        Type type1 = typeof(T);
        ConstructorInfo[] constructors = type1.GetConstructors();
        ConstructorInfo largestConstructor = constructors.OrderByDescending(x => x.GetParameters().Count()).First();
        ParameterInfo[] parameters = largestConstructor.GetParameters();
        List<object> paramValues = new List<object>();
        IModelBinder binder;
        string oldModelName = bindingContext.ModelName;
        foreach (ParameterInfo param in parameters)
        {
            string name = CreateSubPropertyName(oldModelName, param.Name);
            //bindingContext.ModelType = param.ParameterType;
            bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, param.ParameterType);
            bindingContext.ModelName = name;
            if (!System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinders.Binders.TryGetValue(param.ParameterType, out binder))
                binder = System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder;
            object model = binder.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
            paramValues.Add(model);
        }
       // bindingContext.ModelType = typeof(T);
        bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, typeof(T));
        bindingContext.ModelName = oldModelName;
        Debug.WriteLine(Environment.StackTrace); 
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type1, paramValues.ToArray());
        return obj;
    }
}

}
```

The class being bound is as follows. The reason for all of this is that it has no default constructor (to make sure that not-nullables are there):

```
namespace Core.Entities{

[EntityAttribute()]
public class Shipper 
{

    protected Shipper() : this("Undefined")
    {

    }

    public Shipper(string CompanyName)
    {
        this.CompanyName = CompanyName;
        Orders = new List<Order>();
    }

    public virtual int ShipperID { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public virtual string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Phone { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Shipper obj_Shipper;
        obj_Shipper = obj as Shipper;
        if (obj_Shipper == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj_Shipper.CompanyName != this.CompanyName)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return CompanyName.GetHashCode();
    }
}
}
```

And by the way the binder is included in global.asax as follows:

```
            ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Shipper), new CustomBinders.NewShipperBinder<Shipper>());
```

So it will be easy to add the whole lot of entity classes (looping through), since I maintain a list of types of entities.

Thus I have been able to update that entity to the database.

Edit: A bit of icing, here is a stack trace:

```
at NorthwindMVCApp.CustomBinders.NewShipperBinder`1.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) in C:\Users\####\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestFluentNHibernate\NorthwindMVC\NorthwindMVCApp\CustomBinders\NewShipperBinder.cs:line 37
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you already inherited from the DefaultModelBinder? I don't think it is possible to do what you intend - if you create a customer model binder and it implements IModelBinder the class must perform all necessary actions.